# Is this required to cross-validate the results of interpolation?

Tags: cross-validation, matlab, spatial

I have 93 scattered locations rainfall data, I used Matlab [scatteredInterpolant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html) function to interpolate these rainfall values to gridded data. The approach that I used is the natural neighbor method.
I found nothing on Matlab central about the necessity or not to perform cross-validation after that.
I asked this question because I know in the ESRI Arc Map after the co-kriging method interpolation some tools exist to check R2 and RMSE of interpolation. 
In fact, after interpolation, they eliminate some initial known locations values and used method to estimate values in these eliminated locations; to understand what is the accuracy of this method.

I want to know is it necessary to perform cross-validation after interpolation using the natural neighbor method or not.

I really appreciate any suggestion or guidance of you professionals in the statistic.

Comment: Did you look into kriging?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen no I used natural neighbor method.